# Comment Discard not Working

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

Using Stack Exchange IOS App Version 1.2.1 on iPhone 5 runing IOS version 8.1.2 I've had the following problem:

Viewing a post, I inadvertently started creating a comment.  I tried to discard the comment by swiping to the left and then tapping on the red "Discard" button that was displayed, but nothing happened. Repeatedly tapping Discard did nothing, as though the app was frozen. The comment that I was trying to discard consists of a single letter, a capital "J".  Tapping on the back button (the large "<" symbol) in the upper left corner of the screen also did not work.

[image]

Comment: No repro, can discard comments just fine. What app version? What OS? If you disable auto complete of the keyboard, does it work?

Comment: Why the down vote?  Was my question not stated clearly enough?  Is the issue of the Discard button not working not important enough for this community?

Comment: I am using Stack Exchange IOS App Version 1.2.1 and my IOS version is 8.1.2.

Comment: Not my downvote, but here on MSE it's not related to quality. Anyway please add the information to the question itself by editing.